# Check empty select in sqlite?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

How can i check the result of my query? I try this, but when the result is empty - error doesn't shows.

```
$result = sqlite_query($db, "SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE cat=".$_GET["cat"]." AND size".$size.""); 
        if($result !== 0) {
            while ($row = sqlite_fetch_array($result)) { 
                echo '<img src="'.$row['img1'].'" alt="'.$row['id'].'" />'."\r\n"; 
            } 
        } else {
            err2();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [`sqlite_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php) returns a result handle, not the number of rows, so you should not compare it against zero:

> This function will return a result handle or FALSE on failure.

Use [`sqlite_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-num-rows.php) to determine the number of rows returned, e.g.

```
if(sqlite_num_rows($result) !== 0) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Note that you should not use user-provided data by directly incorporating it in the SQL query as that allows for [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also, make sure that the contents of your database, particularly values in columns `img1` and `id` are properly escaped or you risk being vulnerable to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 1):

You could check number of returning rows using sqlite_num_rows() function

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

Looks on http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-num-rows.php

```
$rows = sqlite_num_rows($result);
```

where $rows will be 0 if the result is empty